# PyDev debug mode TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python, eclipse, logging, pydev, nonetype

I am writing a script that uses the logging module to handle the verbosity of the script. I am using the PyDev plugin for Eclipse and running Python 3.2. If I "Run" the script everything works fine, but if I "Debug" the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.2.0.201312292215\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1146, in trace_dispatch
        filename, base = GetFilenameAndBase(frame)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.2.0.201312292215\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 224, in GetFilenameAndBase
        return NORM_FILENAME_AND_BASE_CONTAINER[f]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I couldn't figure out where the error was coming from, so I started commenting out everything and figured out the statement "import logging" is causing the error. Here's the code I'm running:

```
import logging

def main():
    print("Logging import test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've checked to make sure the logging module is with all of the other standard modules in my Python32 install location. Any ideas? Again, this is only when I run PyDev in debug mode; run completes with no errors. Thanks!

Comment: I could not repro the problem with the code you provided.  I'm running Python 3.3 (and the latest PyDev and Eclipse) for what that's worth.

Comment: (hit enter too soon)
I could not repro the problem with the code you provided.  I'm running Python 3.3 (and the latest PyDev and Eclipse) for what that's worth.  But I wonder whether your PYTHONPATH is messed up?  'import logging' should pull in logging from the python interpreter,  but the stack track is coming from PyDev code.  My sample didn't get into PyDev code (nor can I see why it should need to).

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm running python 2.7, eclipse 3.8.1,pydev 3.4.1.   As @BobHy points out, the error is occurring in PyDev code.  I can successfully run my own code (that has nothing to do with logging) and get the desired output, but then I get these error messages at the end.  This has nothing to do with your code, or python (per se).  I don't think it has to do with logging either.  This is some configuration problem with Eclipse.

Comment: or the problem could possibly be with pydev... or both eclipse and pydev...

Comment: I also have the same issue but dont know how to resolve it

Comment: Has there been a known fix to this? I'm experiencing this on Python 2.7, Eclipse (C/C++ version) 4.9.0, PyDev 7.0.3. I haven't found anything else online that has the same problem (without it be connected to another piece of software).